# receiving simple data from other apps and jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

it might be a already asked or maybe a silly question but I could not find an answer regarding my problem.
I'm working on a project where I use jetpack navigation component for navigation and receive some data from another app via a intent filter. When I'm debugging the app, I see that I receive the data in the onCreate but then when I use the navigation controller to pass the data to the fragment (it's not the start destination) then the arguments in the onViewCreated of the fragment are null. I can't really explain the reason.
Is the issue that it navigates first to the start destination and then to that fragment the arguments got lost? Do I need to use deeplinking? Is the issue somewhere else? Any explanation and solution is welcome.

Thanks In advance!

Manifest

```
<application
        android:name="com.example"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ultimate.example.main.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Main Activity

```
private val navController by lazy {
    Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigation_host_fragment)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        setUpNavigation()
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.let {
            val action = it.action
            val type = it.type
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == action && type != null) {
                Timber.e("heey $action")
                Timber.e("heey $type")
                val cardDeckUrl = it.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
                Timber.e("heey $cardDeckUrl")
                val cards = DeckExtractorHelper.extractInformationFromURL(cardDeckUrl)
                Timber.e("${cards[0]}")
                Timber.e("${cards[1]}")
                Timber.e("${cards[2]}")
                
                navController.navigate(R.id.walletFragment,Bundle().apply {
                putIntegerArrayList(CARDS_KEY, cards) })
            }
        }
    }
```

WalletFragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        //TODO figure OUT why arguments are null when passing them from activity to fragment!! 
        arguments?.let {
            it.getIntegerArrayList(MainActivity.CARDS_KEY)?.let { deckListFromGame ->
                viewModel.showDeckFromGame(deckListFromGame)
            }
        }
        initAdapter()
    }
```

Comment: why are you not using a navigation action when navigating?
Can you provide the code where you define the navigation graph for this fragment?
You defined an argument there, didn't you?

Comment: I'm using single live events and navigate by using the navigation component programmatically from the viewmodel. In my navigation graph I've only added the destinations without connect them with actions. So no it does not have any arguments in there.

Comment: How did you get your arguments in the fragment? If you really want to pass your arguments while navigating with jetpack, you could put them in navArgs.

Comment: Did you already find a solution?
One of the most easy solutions is to store your received data in the handling activity and let your fragment check the parent activity for data to handle (e.g. onCreate)